# struts 2 jQuery jqueryui property does not import jquery.ui.js

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

The project is based on struts-jquery-3.6.1
I want to write a widget in the jquery so I change the head tag as below, to import the jQuery UI tags:

```
<sj:head debug="true"           
        jqueryui="true"
        defaultLoadingText="Please wait ..." />
```

It makes an html as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.js?s2j=3.6.1"></script>
```

The jquery.ui.core.js is the core! It does not include jquery.ui.widget.js. 
Do you know what is the best way to solve it?
I do not want to manually add script in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `loadAtOnce` to `true` as well.

```
loadAtOnce  -   do not use the on demand load for jquery ui resources
```

Comment: Thanks. But, is the tag document correct: "do not use the on demand load for jquery ui resources" ?! It seems that we should use the loadAtOnce tag for jquery UI!

Comment: It means it would disable the `on demand loading` , which  only load required scripts when necessary. Use this option when you have your own script which reference the `jqueryui` libraries